# Get result of Python function in Labview and reuse as value for next function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, labview

I try to create a dataframe in a Python function used by Labview. In each LabView loop, I want to concat a DataFrame in a Python function. How can I reuse the output of the last function for the next Python function using Dataframe as output? When I connect the function output, I get the error in LabView: "Polymorphic terminal cannot accept this datatype".

Other DataTypes (e.g. array) are not a problem.

Comment: Is the Dataframe processed at all in LabVIEW? If not, then why not just simply pass the data out as an accepted type (i.e. Array of Bytes, FlattenedString )?

Comment: with array it is much more complicated to pass my values. Rows and columns have index and I also use Multiindex. It would be a mess doing this with arrays.

Comment: You might try TestScript, the free, source-released LabVIEW/Python connector from Genuen, mostly written by yours truly. Anything that can be flattened to JSON can be a parameter in either direction (TestScript is fully bidirectional). As long as a Pandas DataFrame can be flattened to JSON (I haven't tested it, but I would think it could be), you might be able to get this approach to work.

Answer (score 0):

LabVIEW specifically calls out that the only options allowed for passing data to/from Python Nodes are:

- Numerics
- Arrays, including multi-dimensional arrays
- Strings
- Clusters

Given this list of options I would suggest passing your data back/forth to LabVIEW as strings using the option provided by:

- `DataFrame.to_json`
- `pandas.read_json`

With the addition of a few lines of code to the python segment you get your data frame out into LabVIEW in a human readable and parsable datatype.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but .to_csv makes a file and does not convert directly to string. So it is slow because of I/O. There is a option .to_string, but no direct option to  read a dataframe from string.

Comment: The 'to_csv' function returns values to either a path or buf. To take comments directly from the reference page: "Path_or_buf: if None is provided the result is returned as a string". The page I am referencing is: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

Comment: Ok, but then there is still the problem convert the string again back to dataframe. Converting to string is not a problem (see my comment there is a .to_string function) .read_csv needs a path, so I don't know how to handle this.

Comment: 'read_csv' specifies "By file-like object, we refer to objects with a read() method, such as a file handle (e.g. via builtin open function) or StringIO." where a StringIO object can be used a filelike object. 
There are still additional options if CSV string parsing doesnt meet your needs, you could always use 'Dataframe.to_json' and 'pandas.read_json' which again can be used to parse to/from string format.